# StreamError sharing inputs form Sweep Job to Command Job - AzureML SDKv2

Tags: python-3.x, azure-sdk-python, azureml-python-sdk, azuremlsdk

We have AML pipelines (sdk v2) containing three steps i.e training, image_creation and model_selector. We are using command components for these three steps.

All of our steps can **run in isolation** as we save all data and configurations on storage accounts. But there is **no support yet within sdkv2** to allow running of pipeline steps in certain **sequence**. Therefore we are forced to use **dummy input outputs** to link the steps so that they run in a certain order.

This is my pipeline function that creates the components and pipeline:

```
@pipeline()
def train_with_hyperparameters(reg_targets, clf_targets):
    ml_client_registry = get_client_registry()
    ml_client = get_client_workspace(..params...)
    pipeline_job_env = get_env_from_shared_registry(...params..)
    
    try:
        # Creating command component
        train_component = command(
            name="train",
            display_name="Bayesian HPO",
            description="Performs training and produces model",
            inputs={
                "reg_targets": Input(type='string'),
                "clf_targets": Input(type='string')
                ...other inputs here...
            },
            code=e.sources_directory,
            command="python -m train.main_portfolio",
            environment=pipeline_job_env,
            outputs=dict(
                auxilary_output_training = Output(type='uri_file')
            ),
        ).component(
            reg_targets=reg_targets,
            clf_targets=clf_targets,
            ml_datafile=ml_datafile,
            preprocessing_config_file=preprocessing_config_file,
            port_agg_col=port_agg_col,
            tgt_period_col=tgt_period_col,
            gpu_flag=gpu_flag,
            dataset_deploy_flag=dataset_deploy_flag
        ) # type: ignore
        
        search_space = {
            ...lot of parameters here...
        }
        sweep_step = train_component.sweep(
            primary_metric="mean_cv",
            ..settings here...
        )
        sweep_step.set_limits(...limits settings here...)

        #image creator component
        image_creator_component = command(
            name="image-creator",
            display_name="Image Creator",
            description="Image creator step",
            inputs={
                "port_agg_col": Input(type='string'),
                ..other inputs here...,
                "auxilary_link":Input(type='uri_file')
            },
            outputs=dict(
                auxilary_output_image_creator = Output(type='uri_file')
            ),
            code=e.image_creator_sources_directory,
            command="python -m image_creator.image_creator",
            environment=pipeline_job_env,
        ).component(
            port_agg_col=port_agg_col,
            tgt_period_col=tgt_period_col,
            auxilary_link=sweep_step.outputs.auxilary_output_training
        )#type:ignore

        #model selector component
        model_selector_component = command(
            name="model-selector",
            display_name="Model Selector",
            description="Model selector step",
            inputs={
                "model_name": Input(type='string'),
                ...other inputs here...,
                "auxilary_link":Input(type='uri_file')
            },
            code=e.best_model_sources_directory,
            command="python -m best_model_selector.register_best_model",
            environment=pipeline_job_env,
        ).component(
            model_name=model_name, 
            ..other values for inputs...,
            auxilary_link=image_creator_component.outputs.auxilary_output_image_creator
        )#type:ignore
        return
    except Exception as excp:
        logging.error('Unable to create command component.')
        raise excp
```

Here you can see three components:

[image]

How I am configuring the output from train source script, added argument:

```
parser.add_argument('--auxilary_output_training', type=str,
                        help="Auxiliar output for following steps in aml pipeline")
```

How I configure the auxilary_link(Input) in image_creator source script is:

```
parser.add_argument('--auxilary_link',
                        type=str,
                        help="""Just a dummy input to connect steps in AML pipeline""")
```

The problem:

The sweep steps uses a train script and inside that script I use:

```
joblib.dump(final_fit_zir, args.auxilary_output_training)
```

Just to dump the file which is model joblib. And passes this output as input to the next image_creator step.

In UI, I can see the sweep step produces the output and all the trial runs also produces this output:
Parent run:
[image]

Child runs(Trials):
[image]

In both of above images, the output name is auxilary_output_training, which should be used as input by the image_creator step as:
[image]

And inUI, the image_creator step inputs are also shown:

[image]

**And the id of outputs in parens and child runs and id of input in image creator steps are same.**

But, I receive StreamError:
[image]

No code related logs are there because the job fails before it runs.

Any help/clue would be appreciated.

Thanks,